# Remove filter of a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I have a review plugin that overrides the comment form in a specific posttype.
Now I'm trying to seperate the reviews and comments.

My first step is to remove the filter that modifies the current comment template and use that filter inside a second comment form.

The plugin uses this code (simplified)

```
final class DM_Reviews {

    public function hooks() {
        do_action_ref_array( 'dm_reviews_before_setup_actions', array( &$this ) );

        add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', array( $this, 'reviews_form'       ) );        

        do_action_ref_array( 'dm_reviews_after_setup_actions', array( &$this ) );
    }

    public function review_form( $args ) {    

            $form = 'plugin code to modify form';   

        return wp_parse_args( $form, $args );
    }

}
```

In my child theme's function.php file, I tried to use this but it didn't worked.

```
global $DM_Reviews;
remove_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', array($DM_Reviews, 'reviews_form'),1 );
```

[WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter)

If someone can put me in the right direction on how to solve it, it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve this goal, using one of the following solutions depending on the way this plugin instantiates the class:

```
if( class_exists('DM_Reviews' ) ){
  //This should work in whatever case, not tested
  remove_filter('comment_form_defaults', array( 'DM_Reviews', 'reviews_form'));
  //or Instantiating a new instance, not tested
  remove_filter('comment_form_defaults', array( new DM_Reviews(), 'reviews_form'));
  //or Targeting the specific instance, not tested
  remove_filter('comment_form_defaults', array( DM_Reviews::get_instance(), 'reviews_form'));
}
```

Hope it helps, let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: @kiarashi pls check the name of the function: "reviews_form" or "review_form"?

Comment: Thanks to you, it worked. :D  I first used all three, but then I tried each one of them seperately. And this one worked: `remove_filter('comment_form_defaults', array( EDD_Reviews::get_instance(), 'reviews_form'));`

Answer (score 1):

for me remove_filter didn't work from function.php i wanted to remove a specific behavior of a plugin so what i did :

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_filters' );

function remove_filters(){
    global $wp_filter;
    unset( $wp_filter["_filter_name"]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
$instance = DM_Reviews::this();
remove_filter('comment_form_defaults', array( $instance, 'reviews_form'));
```

Comment: I'm afraid I received an error when using it like that. `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DM_Reviews::this()`